# python matplotlib не корректные данные

Tags: python, matplotlib

Всем доброго времени.
Использую  matplotlib в python для создания графиков.
пытаюсь в цикле сделать графики  для нескольких пользователей.

В итоге сохраняет для 1 верно, а для остальных погода на марсе.
не пойму, что не так.
если вызвать одного пользователя, то график верный, если в цикле для нескольких происходит какое то смещение, будто, данные пишутся со 2 пользователя, и дальше они записываются для каждого.
Пробовал делать задержку, без результата.

```
def week_grafik():
    today = date.today()
    seller=users_id_api()
    for i in seller:
        x=['Пон-ник','Вторник','Среда', 'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота', 'Воск-нье']
        y=pos_info_graf_today(i[0])
        print(i[0],y)
        print(len(y),i[0])
        if len(y)==7:
            plt.bar(x, y, label='Сумма продаж')
            plt.xlabel('Неделя')
            plt.ylabel('Прибыль, в руб.')
            plt.legend()
            #plt.show()
            plt.savefig(f'{i[0]}-{today}.png')
            #plt.close(f'{i[0]}-{today}.png')
        else:
            print("Дней торговли меньше 7")
        time.sleep(30)
        print("Ожидание 30 секунд")
week_grafik()
```

Comment: ничего не понятно, но очень интересно. приведите в вопросе код, воспроизводящий проблему. с данными.

Comment: вроде все расписал, код  есть,
пытаюсь сделать график и сохранить его в png

Comment: я смогу воспроизвести ошибку, выполнив приведенный вами код?

Comment: Я так понимаю, основная магия происходит в функции `pos_info_graf_today`, которую вы не показали. Вам нужно проверить, те ли данные она выдаёт, которые вы ожидали.

Comment: А, ещё добавьте перед `plt.bar(...)` строку `plt.figure()`, сейчас у вас наверное на одной картинке всё рисуется, а не на разных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не делать вызов `plt.figure()`, то каждый следующий вызов какой-то отрисовки, например, `plt.bar(...)` происходит на том же графике, он дорисовывает данные на той же картинке. Чтобы рисовка была каждый раз "с чистого листа", нужно каждый раз в начале отрисовки вызывать `plt.figure()`:

```py
        ...
        if len(y)==7:
            plt.figure() # <-- начинаем с пустой картинки
            plt.bar(x, y, label='Сумма продаж')
            ...
```

Comment: Супер,все получилось.работает как часики.
Спасибо Вам БОЛЬШОЕ!!!